# Sublime snippet for Google fonts not working

Tags: fonts, sublimetext3, code-snippets

So I wanted to created a snippet for generating a specific Google font in Sublime Text 3, mainly for speeding up workflow.

This is my snippet (based on Roboto):

```xml
<snippet>
    <content>
        <![CDATA[
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        ]]>
    </content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>gf-roboto</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

When opening an html file and inputting my tabTrigger **(gf-roboto)**, nothing happens. I am really confused, I've created snippets like this before but this is a first this is happening. On tab nothing happens.

Any suggestions would be really helpful, I'm up to try anything as long as I can get this to work.

Thank you

Comment: It works fine for me. What did you save the file as and where did you save it?

Comment: As per MattDMo's question: where's the rest of the information? This is not a snipper in a "new file" tab that's not been saved, so what'd you call it, where did you store it, and where are you indicating which file to load, using which syntax?